# Matlab save figure containing large number of elements as bitmap

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to save a 3D figure that I have generated using `scatter3` with the following command:

```
set(gcf,'PaperPositionMode','auto')
print -zbuffer -dtiff -r300 figure_name.tif
```

on Matlab running on a Mac.

Upon executing the command the CPU load increases but nothing happened. I have waited for about 24 hours to no avail. I have tried the same on a very well specced Windows workstation with

```
print -opengl -dtiff -r300 figure_name.tif
```

but that didn't make any difference.

Normally for figures that contain fewer data points this command works very well and produces decent output in a matter of seconds.

I can save the figure in `.fig` format but what I really need is a decent resolution image file. The figure contains about 1 million data points and it shows up on the screen without too much delay when I plot it. I have tried reducing the number of data points to 200,000 but this also does not work. For a plot with less than 40,000 data points it does work, no matter whether I am on my Windows (64bit, 48 GB RAM) or Mac (64bit, 4 GB RAM) system. However, I need at least 100,000 data points to illustrate what I want to show.

And no luck with this:

```
print(gcf,'-dpng','figure_name.png');
```

I also tried the `Save As` option in the figure GUI but that's not doing any better either.

Essentially I have to kill the Matlab task to stop this task. <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> does not help.

Does anyone have an idea how I could get my high resolution .tif file (can be any bitmap format really)?

Comment: I've had good luck using [export_fig](https://sites.google.com/site/oliverwoodford/software/export_fig) to generate images from Matlab figures.

Comment: what is wrong with `saveas(gcf,'d:/img.tiff');` ?

Comment: Wouldn't saving to eps be more efficient (since it is a vector format?) You can later then rasterize it in photoshop or whatever software you use...

Comment: @nate It's not quite the one stop solution I hoped that I could find but I tried it and it works. Thanks for reminding me of this - I should have given this a go before myself I guess :)